# Going through all sheets in a workbook and iterate through their tables

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple sheets in a excel workbook, each sheet has a table. I want to select all sheets in an object so I can iterate through them by selecting tables in a `set` object one by one.

How can I do this?

Comment: A range is in a sheet, not the opposite. Sheets cannot be in a range. You should rephrase your question

Comment: I want to select all sheets in an object so I can iterate through them by selecting tables in a set object one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
        Debug.Print ws.Name, tbl.Name, tbl.Range.Address
    Next tbl
Next ws
```

I found [this page](http://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables) and [this one](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel2007TablesVBA.asp) that cover the subject.

---

Edit: as you seem to have used `Tables` to speak about simple `Ranges`, here is a `Range` oriented alternative:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Debug.Print ws.Name, Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address
Next ws
```

Comment: Thankyou, I am able to get sheets through this but `ws.ListObjects.Count` remains zero. What constitutes as a table in excel, my sheets have data in cell and rows, that should be considered as table?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub LoopThroughAllTablesinWorkbook()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects

            'Your code here...

        Next tbl
    Next sht

End Sub
```